# Is there way to specify number of processors for CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have been working on CUDA for a while. I am wondering whether there is a way to specify number of processor within running command. I have checked `nvcc -help`, but I couldn't come up with a proper result.

For example, for MPI we can specify this via following code

```
mpirun -np <number of processes> <program name and arguments>
```

Comment: Do you mean the number of processors that `nvcc` uses to compile the code with?

Comment: Yes. I am going to evaluate performance of my code with different number of processors.

Comment: @user853005: That's both a yes and a no. If you want to use different number of processors for running your own code then that's not what flipchart asked.  And in that case, firstly nvcc has nothing to do with it.  Secondly, the question is what you mean by "processors".  Is it the number of GPUs in a multi-GPU system or the number of CUDA cores of a single GPU?

Comment: The short answer is no. CUDA deliberately abstracts all the details of the hardware away. There is no control over how code runs on the hardware beyond the grid and block configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVCC does not support this activity. CUDA manages this Itself based on the current hardware configuration and thread block size and grid size for optimizing GPU capacity. But you can write some code for select device for kernels execution if you have more than one graphic card.